# Redirect to non-static controller

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using Spring Data in my Play! application like in the following [template](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-spring-data-jpa/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.java).

In the template the controller actions are NOT implemented as static methods:

```
public Result index() {
    //...
}
```

I'm having trouble to return a redirect from one of my controller actions. Usually, with static controller actions, I would do the following:

```
return redirect(
    routes.SomeController.someStaticMethod()
);
```

This does not work however. How do I redirect to a non-static action?

Comment: Why doesn't this work?  The reverse router just returns basically a url that the redirect method uses to set the http response.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, James. I must have messed sth. up because as you suggested, it works.